# Getting address of the function into the structure in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
typedef void (*MenuItemFunctionPtr) () ; 

struct MenuItem{
    char *TextToDisplayPtr;
    MenuItemFunctionPtr MenuItemFunctionPointer;
    struct MenuItem *NextMenuItem;
    struct MenuItem *SubMenuItem;
};

void MenuItemAFunction ();
```

I tried to define my structure in few ways:

```
struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, MenuItemAFunction(), &MenuItemB, 0};
struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, MenuItemAFunction, &MenuItemB, 0};
struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, &MenuItemAFunction(), &MenuItemB, 0};
struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, &MenuItemAFunction, &MenuItemB, 0};
```

but I always get errors about function pointer, they differ according to which way i want to define it so i guess there must be other way but I don't know how to do it properly.

How do I populate the `MenuItem` structure?

Comment: What's the error you get on that last one?  It seems the most correct.  In general, including your error messages will make it easier for folks to help you.

Comment: Like `fmoo`, I think the last is closet to what you need. But you might *not* need the last `address of` operator: `struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, &MenuItemAFunction, MenuItemB, 0};`. The compiler error will tell us.

Comment: The easiest way to check you function pointer declaration is to try: `MenuItemFunctionPtr pfn = &MenuItemAFunction;`. If that's OK, then the problem is in another `struct` member (or elsewhere).

Comment: MenuItemFunctionPtr pfn = &MenuItemAFunction; is ok . but when i try struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, &MenuItemAFunction, MenuItemB, 0}; i get this errors: 1. undefined reference to 'MenuItemAFunction' 2. ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old-style function declarations are deprecated in C. That is to say:

```
void MenuItemAFunction();
```

means, in C, that `MenuItemAFunction` a function which returns nothing, but which takes an unknown number of arguments or unknown types: the declaration says almost nothing about the argument list.

The proper way to declare a function which takes no arguments is:

```
void MenuItemAFunction(void);
```

> Side note: in C++, this is different. The `()` syntax nicely declares a function with no arguments. Bjarne Stroustrup listened to advisors when he was working on "C with Classes" that became C++. Dennis Ritchie called `(void)` an "abomination". So Stroustrup was convinced to make `()` have the obvious meaning.

**Thus, you may be getting diagnostics related to this obsolete usage.** Fix that issue; try again.  These two variants should work:

```
struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, MenuItemAFunction, &MenuItemB, 0};
struct MenuItem MenuItemA = {textA, &MenuItemAFunction, &MenuItemB, 0};
```

The address-of `&` operator is not necessary, because an expression which denotes a function (such as a primary function which consists of an identifier that is a function name) already evaluates to a pointer without the address-of operator.

You don't want to be expressing a function call if the intent is to take that function's address: no combination of syntax can be placed around `MenuItemAFunction()` to make a pointer to the function come out of that expression.

**Your remaining "undefined reference" error stems from the fact that you have only *declared* the function `MenuItemAFunction`, not *defined* it.** You cannot take the address of a function which doesn't exist. Perhaps your project (Makefile, IDE, ...) is set up incorrectly and not compiling and linking in the source file which containst he definition of that function.

Comment: The second assignment does not what the asker expects. He'd then store a `pointer to pointer to a function` and not a `pointer to a function` as he typedefed and used in the struct.

Comment: @drahnr I'm afraid you need to read some basic C tutorials. The expressions `&malloc` and `malloc` (for instance), when evaluated, are equivalent. Both of them yield a pointer-to-function.

Comment: Kaz I tried what you have told me but I still get the same 2 errors which i wrote above in the comment.

Comment: @user3023499 Updated. Your undefined reference stems from not having defined the function, only declared it.

Comment: OMG you are right ;) it works i thought i dont need to define it, only decalre it to recall to this function. You know like with the variables.

Comment: @user3023499 There is no difference with regard to variables. External variables which are used must also be defined. However, the C syntax is such that certain declarations are actually definitions too. `int x;` at file scope actually declares **and** defines `x`, but `int f(void);` only declares `f`. But `extern int x;` likewise only declares `x`. Confusingly though, `extern int x = 42;`, again, **defines** x.